# Using CURL to download without a direct path | www.url.com/things?download=file

Tags: php, curl, download, get

How does one download a file from a web page without a direct path to the file. For example a URL with `GET` information instead of the path. The code below seems to be downloading the actual page html instead of the file...

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. I also would like to augment this to also perform on sites that require logins but I think I would just have to add

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password")
```

to the code?

```
$output_filename = "advanced.exe";

$host = "http://download.cnet.com/Advanced-SystemCare-Free/3001-2086_4-10407614.html?hlndr=1";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $host);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://download.cnet.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$fp = fopen($output_filename, 'w');
fwrite($fp, $result);
fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 0):

The link you have there isn't the actual link to the file, only the page that initiates the download. By the looks of it, the page uses JavaScript to trigger the download, so you would want to dig through their code to find out exactly how they do it. Then you can find the real URL to the file.

A simple way, if you are doing this only for one file, would be to download the file in your browser, and then access the URL it used from the browser's download manager. (In Firefox, for example, right click the file and choose "Copy Download Link")

> I also would like to augment this to also perform on sites that require logins but I think I would just have to add ...

That would work only for HTTP based authentication. If the site uses a traditional login form, this will not work. You'd have to submit several, sequential HTTP requests via CURL, using cookies to store the session state.